# Animate element by mouseover and animate.css

Tags: jquery, css, animate.css

Is it possible to animate element by mouseover and [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/)?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").mouseover(function(){
        $("p").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#mystyle").animateCss('bounce');
    });
    $("p").mouseout(function(){
        $("p").css("background-color", "gray");
    });
});
```

I tried it but something is wrong.
https://jsfiddle.net/f79b7033/

Comment: If you want to use the `animateCss` function you will need to include it in your code. Check my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation in animation.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/#usage), you can extend the jQuery using:

```
$.fn.extend({
    animateCss: function (animationName) {
        var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
        this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        });
    }
});
```

And you didn't add it in your code.

Here is a working example (including the above code):
https://jsfiddle.net/dekelb/9jaq7fhr/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with animate.css but opening the console you get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).animateCss is not a function
    at HTMLParagraphElement.<anonymous> ((index):53)
    at HTMLParagraphElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
    at HTMLParagraphElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
```

So i looked at the documentation for animate.css and found this:

`$('#yourElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');`

Added that instead and here is your fiddle - looks like it is working:

https://jsfiddle.net/f79b7033/3/

**EDIT:** 
Dekel pointed out that the above error was caused by not extending Jquery (see his answer for how to do that). This is the non-jQuery version.

Comment: Using the `addClass` is an option, but if you want to use the `animateCss` function you will need to extend jQuery. Read my answer for more information regarding this.

Comment: @Dekel Makes sense. Guess I didn't read far enough into the documentation :) Upvoted your answer as it is the better answer, I'll make an edit explaining mine is the non-Jquery way of doing it